# How To Use Libevent In Golang?(Golang DLL)

Tags: c++, go

I need Help in Golang with C++ .

**Project History:**

1. I have a c++ Application for Game over 10 years.
2. Now I try to Rewrite it in Golang.
3. I find the old use libEvent and I try to package c++ to DLL and use DLL in Golang.

**Issue:**

When I Try To Use Code Like:

> in Cpp-DLL

```
event * Go_event_new(struct event_base *, event_callback_fn, void *)
```

> in Golang

```
m_pRpcEvent := api.Cpp_event_new(uintptr(p.PROP_m_pEventBase), uintptr(rpcFunc), uintptr(this))
```

**It returns an error and makes a memory leak.

How Can I Do For LibEvent?

Comment: Go programs typically use synchronous code running in goroutines for IO.  You should consider converting from evented IO to the Go way of doing things in your port.

Comment: Why does the function name `Cpp_event_new` invoked in Go not correspond to the interface name `Go_event_new` of Cpp-DLL?

Comment: You might want to read this before developing a Golang program interfacing with C/C++ : https://dave.cheney.net/2016/01/18/cgo-is-not-go

Comment: Another thing is that you manually allocate from "Go world" a object/struct in "C world", but Go has no clue about what's happening in "C world", therefore Go is not garbage-collecting anything. You have to manager your "C world" memory by yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot about everyone,I finish it in C# refactor the old appliacation,not in golang